# Avoid plotting the same line twice

Tags: python, algorithm

I have pairs of items (in Python), with one list holding the first half and a second list holding the second half. Each pair appears twice, in the form of `a -> b` and also `b -> a`.

Every value that is paired up has a corresponding 2D coordinate that is stored in a third array and I want to graph every pair as dots on a scatter plot and then graph a line joining their coordinates together. How do I avoid plotting the same 2 items twice?

The nieve solution is to check whether both `a` and `b` have already been plotted as dots but this won't work if pairs like `c -> b` and `a -> c` both appear earlier.

That means I'll need to check whether specifically the pair of coordinates have been plotted before.

I believe both of these solutions run in `O(n^2)` time. Is there a solution that runs in `O(n)` time?

Here's an example:

```py
import torch

# Each use of `torch.randn` is a placeholder for actual values but imitates the shape
t_a = torch.randn(3, 256, 256)
t_b = torch.randn(3, 256, 256)
t_c = torch.randn(3, 256, 256)
t_d = torch.randn(3, 256, 256)

a = [t_a, t_b, t_c]
b = [t_b, t_a, t_d]

c_keys = [t_a, t_b, t_c]
c_values = [torch.randn(2), torch.randn(2), torch.randn(2)]
```

Comment: It would be helpful If I have [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe you could sort the pairs a -> b and b -> a so that the lowest goes first, i.e. a -> b, a -> b and then you could remove duplicates, then draw the lines.

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of all of the drawn coordinates in a set.

```py
plotted_lines = set()

for single_a, single_b in zip(a, b):
  if (single_a, single_b) not in plotted_lines and (single_b, single_a) not in plotted_lines:
    plot(single_a, single_b)
    plotted_lines.add((single_a, single_b))
```